# Find all parents in hierarchical SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Using ASP.NET 4.5 and EF 6, I've put together a multilevel data model that looks like this:

**Organization**, which has an ICollection of:

_____**Workspaces**, which has an ICollection of:

__________**Projects**, which has an ICollection of:

_______________**Cards**

If I've got a Card Id, how do I find the parents above it? I can't even figure out how to get one level of parent. To find the Project that is the parent of a card with Id of myCardId, I want to write something like:

```
var project = db.Projects.Where(p => p.Cards.Where(c => c.Id == myCardId));
```

Any guidance? Good tutorials you can point me to?

---

Update: Here's my Project model:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }   
}
```

And here's my Card:

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }          
}
```

When I look at the tables in the database, the Card has a Project_Id column, but that happened magically from something Entity Framework did - I believe. Because the Card model has no Parent object on it, I can't programatically ask for things like Card.Project.Workspace.Organization...

Did I set up the whole thing backward?

Comment: Your `Cards` table should have a `Project` Object or `ProjectId` in it. You can use that to find all the project for the cards.

Comment: Using child table also filter parent table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that find the parents means go up in the Hierarchy so you should be able to write somethin like 
'var project = db.Projects.Where(p => p.Cards.Where(c => c.Id == myCardId));'

```
var t= db.Cards.where(x=> x.id==myCardId).Select(y=> y.Project.Workspace.Organization);
```

//this should return the organization

Comment: Would love that approach to work. Added updates to my original post trying to explain why I can't programmatically access parents (they're not on the models). I think EF sets up the foreign keys for each child using the ICollection statement on the parent. So because there's no Parent property on the model, I can't access up the chain in code.

Comment: you can added or use joins or use this dirty stament db.Organization.selectMAny(x=> x.Workspace).selectMany(y=> y.Projects).selectMAny(e=> e.Cards).where(i=> i.Id== cardId);

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have references for each tables.

so you can get the organization by.

```
var organization = (from o in Organization
                    from w in Workspaces
                    from p in Projects
                    from c in Cards
                    where c.Id == myCardId && p.projectid == c.projectid && w.workspaceid == p.workspaceid && o.organizationid == w.organizationid select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

if its different from your code then post your collection structure here, so that anyone can help.

Comment: Ooooh, that sure looks like something I want. However, VS2015 tells me that it "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Organization'. 'Select Many' not found". I'm sure it would complain about types below Organization, but that's the first one it flags. Does that mean I don't have references to tables set up properly?

Comment: Yes, You need to link your collections first. try to add references for each. Like your `_____Workspaces need to be referenced with Organizationid from ___Organization` and your `__________Projects need to be referenced with Workspacesid from _____Workspaces ` and `________Cards need to be referenced with Projectsid from __________Projects `

Answer (score 1):

Your Model should be like this:

```
public class Project
{
  public int projectId { get; set; }
  public int workspaceId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }   
}

public class Card
{
  public int cardId { get; set; }
  public int projectId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  public string Notes { get; set; }          
}
```

Your Card table should have reference to projectid, and project table should have reference to workspaceid, and workspace table should have reference to organisationid.

Then you can use karthikb2win's query to get Organization or any parent tables.

Comment: interesting, I'd already tried exactly that (essentially). Database operations throw an error like this "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Projects'. Only one identity column per table is allowed." I suppose i could just label the fields as "ParentProject" or something without the letters "id"....

Comment: only primarykey field should be identity(i.e projectId). Remove identity from other fields. Are you using code first approach or creating tables in SQL itself?